# jQuery plugin not getting applied to $.ajax dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

**Disclaimer:**
I know this type of question has been asked here before, I just can't seem to find it. I have tried searching for a bunch of different `$.ajax dynamic` + `live()` type stuff but can't find the solution, anyway, here is the problem.

**Problem:**

I am building a site where I can save my pieces of code. I am having the content pulled from a database via `$.ajax.` Here is the website: [InsanelyWeb.com](http://insanelyweb.com) the select box options content is also dynamic. Try the options **HTML** > **DOCTYPE** > **HTML4 Strict** (as that is the only one working right now.)

As you can see, there is static content that has the SyntaxHighlighter plugin getting applied. But when I follow the above select options, and data is pulled from the database, it loses the plugin. I am assuming it is because the content is dynamic and I can't have stuff applied to it. This is the code I have.

**jQuery:**

```
$('#labels').live('change', function() {
    getScripts();
});

$.ajax({
    url: './db_scripts/get_scripts.php',
    success: function( data ) {
        var dataObj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        $.each(dataObj, function() {
            $('#code').html( this.code );
        })
        highlighter(); //after success, initiates highlighter 
    },
});

function highlighter() {
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
}
```

**Question:**

How can I have the plugin applied to dynamic content? I have tried `async: false` but I don't think that is the solution. Thank you very much for your time.

---

**Solution:**

Explain (very nicely) below:

```
function highlighter() {
    SyntaxHighlighter.highlight()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I see the problem is that the *hightlight* function is [called just once](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/SyntaxHighlighter/blob/master/scripts/shCore.js#L353) (on window.load).

Try to call the *SyntaxHighlighter.highlight()* function yourself in your ajax callback function.

**Update** (elaboration):

`SyntaxHighlighter.highlight()` is the function that highlight all elements on the page that are marked as SyntaxHighlighter source code.

`SyntaxHighlighter.all()` just register the `highlight()` function for the *window.load* event. I think it's to be sure that the DOM is loaded before appling the SyntaxHighlighter.

If you call `SyntaxHighlighter.all()` more than once, it just registers the `highlight()` function once more. Because your are doing an ajax request, the *window.load* event isn't fired anymore. So you can call `SyntaxHighlighter.highlight()` directly.

Comment: What do you mean? I have `hightlight()` being called on the `.success()` of the final `$.ajax` call, do you mean additional to that?

Comment: I tried to use the `complete:` function and it did not work. I am assuming by calling `:all` it doesn't re-apply the event to the window?